# Windows console handle for con device

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-console

I use `_get_osfhandle` and `_isatty` (MinGW) to get File handles from CRT file descriptors and determine if they write to a console. But if a file is a `con` device, some WINAPI functions don't work. For example, `WriteConsole` works well, but `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo` and `SetConsoleTextAttribute` do not. `stdout`and other standard streams are redirected to files, so I can't use `GetStdHandle`. Is there another way to get a console handle in my case, to not only print text on console, but change its color too?

Comment: `GetStdHandle` always return correct handle, regardless this true console handle or redirected to file handle. so you can always use this. however `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo` and `SetConsoleTextAttribute` will be work only this real console handle, and fail for redirected handle

Comment: The WinAPI "CON" device (i.e. "\Device\ConDrv\Console" in NT 6.3+) can only be opened for read or write access, but not both, because the requested access determines whether the system should open the input buffer or the active screen buffer. Many functions in the console API require read-write access to a console buffer, so they cannot be used with a handle opened via "CON". If you need to use such functions you should explicitly open "CONIN$" or "CONOUT$" (i.e. "\Device\ConDrv\CurrentIn" and "\Device\ConDrv\CurrentOut", respectively).

Comment: Note that `_isatty` only determines whether the underlying File handle references a character device (from calling `GetFileType`), so it's not limited to only console handles. For example, both serial communication devices and the NUL device are character devices. The way the CRT detects a console handle is to call `GetConsoleMode`. This will necessarily fail for a screen-buffer handle opened via "CON", since the handle lacks read access.